# The script rio is installed in '/root/.local/bin' which is not on PATH

Tags: google-ai-platform

I get this warming while training a model in Google AI Platform with "gcloud ai-platform jobs submit training". My understanding is that the path is irrelevant here as the installation happens in the cloud. Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: Hi, were you able to resolve it? Getting the same error